# yum/dnf asking and caching repo changes again for different users

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, yum, dnf

In Debian Linux after running `sudo apt-get update`, all users asking for info, `apt-cache show package_name`, get the system-wide saved info. No need to access the Internet or local apt cache server again.

In contrast, on both Centos (v7-8) and Fedora (v32), I've noticed that even after `sudo yum upgrade` (or `dnf`), if a user types `yum info package_name` (or `dnf`) all repos are read and cached again. The same happens if another user tries, etc. Apparently the caching is user based, not system-wide.

Is my assumption correct? Any way to make yum/dnf behave like apt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my assumption correct?

Yes. This is described in [the `dnf` manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/dnf.8.html):

> DNF uses a separate cache for each user under which it
> executes. The cache for the root user is called the system
> cache. This switch allows a regular user read-only access to
> the system cache, which usually is more fresh than the user’s
> and thus he does not have to wait for metadata sync.

> Any way to make yum/dnf behave like apt?

Yes; you can make `dnf` update the system cache by running `dnf mc` as root, and then run it as non-root with the `-C` (or `--cacheonly`) switch:

> Run entirely from system cache, don’t update the cache and use
> it even in case it is expired.

The user caches will be ignored and won’t be updated.